# Issues with selection of DATES between START and END dates

Tags: oracle

The tables have below values for TRANSACTION_DATE

```
TRANSACTION_DATE in tables
    13-APR-17
    06-JUL-17
    17-JUL-17
```

FROM UI below values are passed to start and end dates:

```
V_TRANSACTION_DATE_START := 06-JUL-17
V_TRANSACTION_DATE_END : = 06-JUL-18
```

Below Condition checks for dates and I suppose to get last 2 July transactions but my query is not picking anyone

```
NVL(TRANSACTION_DATE,TRUNC(SYSDATE)) BETWEEN NVL(V_TRANSACTION_DATE_START,NVL(TRANSACTION_DATE,TRUNC(SYSDATE))) 
                                                            AND NVL(V_TRANSACTION_DATE_END,NVL(TRANSACTION_DATE,TRUNC(SYSDATE)))
```

Any help is Appreciated !

Comment: Are you sure all the years are 2000s? Database values might be 1917, not 2017. Change the date format to show full year, and to specify full year when assigning start/end dates.

Comment: In your table, is the TRANSACTION_DATE column defined as date or timestamp?

Comment: @Andreas , I got it after change of date format in my query ... will update once i test from UI ... UI went down now :-(  ...its TRANSACTION_DATE  is DATE daatype

Comment: In Oracle, date literals are written like `date '2017-07-06'` not `06-JUL-17` - [see the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code block :

```
declare
  V_TRANSACTION_DATE_START varchar2(80) := '06-JUL-17';
  V_TRANSACTION_DATE_END   varchar2(80) := '06-JUL-18'; 

  TRANSACTION_DATE         varchar2(80) := '17-JUL-17'; 
begin

  if NVL(TRANSACTION_DATE,TRUNC(SYSDATE)) 
     BETWEEN NVL(V_TRANSACTION_DATE_START,NVL(TRANSACTION_DATE,TRUNC(SYSDATE))) 
         AND NVL(V_TRANSACTION_DATE_END,NVL(TRANSACTION_DATE,TRUNC(SYSDATE))) then
    dbms_output.put_line('Char collation returns '||
                                        TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TRANSACTION_DATE,'DD-MON-YY'),'DD-MM-YYYY'));
  end if;     

  if NVL(TO_DATE(TRANSACTION_DATE,'DD-MON-YY'),TRUNC(SYSDATE)) 
     BETWEEN NVL(TO_DATE(V_TRANSACTION_DATE_START,'DD-MON-YY'),NVL(TRANSACTION_DATE,TRUNC(SYSDATE))) 
         AND NVL(TO_DATE(V_TRANSACTION_DATE_END  ,'DD-MON-YY'),NVL(TRANSACTION_DATE,TRUNC(SYSDATE))) then
    dbms_output.put_line('Date collation returns '||
                                        TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TRANSACTION_DATE,'DD-MON-YY'),'DD-MM-YYYY'));                                          
  end if;                                          
end;
```

returns only the result of the second statement :

`Date collation returns 17-07-2017`

as result.

*Therefore, you need to make a date conversion with the proper format( `DD-MON-YY` is the case here)*

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/JIY34345)